# Determining if your otp design has bottlenecks

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

If you design your OTP hierarchy incorrectly, what kind of errors will you see in production?

Say there is a bottleneck where you don't have enough workers and your code blocks, is it basically timeout errors?

Is there a way to monitor if you have a bottleneck?

I know you can write benchmarks I'm sure, can someone please point me to a good benchmarking example for this type of test?

Comment: I think it may be worth your while to read a book on the subject.  This [one](https://www.amazon.com/Designing-Scalability-Erlang-OTP-Fault-Tolerant/dp/1449320732) is one that seems to cover the subject well.  As far as I can tell, the questions you're asking are a bit too much to cover in one simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from improper supervision tree design, another common mistake is sending too many messages to one process. The process will become a bottleneck in a way that they have too many messages in process mailbox. And sending a message to a large mailbox is even more expensive in erlang VM. With the default process priority setting,  it will block the caller process(like you trying to use GenServer.call) and thus those process will quickly become the bottleneck in your system. Timeout will most likely to occur in this situation.

While you can use `Process.info(pid, :message_queue_len)` to check the message queue size, there is a library like [recon](https://github.com/ferd/recon) to help you monitor like info process, VM in runtime. And in development, my go-to is to simply run `:observer.start` in iex. Erlang [Observer](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/observer/observer_ug.html) offers a great intuitive way to inspect system information, supervisor trees, and process information.

Answer (score 0):

> Say there is a bottleneck where you don’t have enough workers and your code blocks, is it basically timeout errors?

One cannot defend from “not enough workers” issue until the real conditions are explicitly stated. Having 1M of workers for 1 message per hour is extremely inefficient; having 1 worker for 1M messages per a second is blocking. There is no silver bullet. *Sidenote:* for this particular kind of problem we use [`GenStage`](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage) to handle back pressure.

---

The most common issue AFAICT is the improper design of the supervision tree, when a crash of one of the workers results in inconsistent state (other workers have an obsolete references to this one or like.) The example would be a worker that keeps a remote connection to say *RabbitMQ*. When the latter crashes, one should restart/reconfigure all the dependents.

That kind of issues is easy to test. One writes a bunch of tests that crash everybody in the supervision tree and ensures that everything is working fine after the crashed one resurrected.

Being explicitly optimized for highload, *ErlangVM* is ready to handle somewhat common out of the box, and when one meets the very uncommon conditions, there is no receipt save for understanding where the bottleneck is (it always sits somewhere you could never think of btw :) and fixing *this particular issue*.

I doubt there could any generic solution ever exist.